# JS: Is it possible to transfer objects with references to other objects from webworkers?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

Part of my program involves parsing text into data structures that use references to other objects within the structure. Due to the way it fits in the program, it would be the perfect candidate for WebWorkers, as it can be done while other things are being calculated, and doesn't rely on any other data than what's passed into it.

Lets use the following webworker code for example:

```
self.onmessage = (e) => {
    let a;
    let b;
    let c;

    a = {
        obj1: b,
        obj2: c
    }

    b = {
        obj1: a,
        obj2: a
    }

    c = {
        obj1: b,
        obj2: b
    }

    let myArr = [a, b, c];

    self.postMessage(myArr);
}
```

currently if I generate this in a web worker and return `myArr`, obj1 and obj2 of each of the elements are undefined. Is there any way to get these references out of the webworker?

Comment: Can you `JSON.stringify(myArr)` in worker, then `JSON.parse(e.message)` in main file?

Comment: Hm, weird. I thought this is what JS was doing anyways behind the scenes but I guess not. Either way, it doesn't really work. Even after modifying the code tho instantiate a, b, and c, using a class, it just seems that goes through the tree an copies the object values IE: if I make a change to `b` then `a.obj1` (which references b) would not reflect that change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I figured it out. I was misunderstanding how references work, and that was leading to my errors.

the issue was I was reassigning the objects, and breaking the references before posting them back to the main thread.

So instead of

```
let a;
let b;

a = {ref: b}
b = {ref: a}
```

In the above example, `b` starts out being undefined, meaning when we assign it to `a.ref`, `a.ref = undefined`, and when we assign `b.ref = a` `b` is now `b = {ref: {ref: undefined}}`

To fix this, I needed to make sure that the variables were assigned to their objects first

```
let a = {ref: null}
let b = {ref: null}

a.ref = b;
b.ref = a;
```

Once I fixed this everything seemed to work fine, and changing `b` now updates `a.ref` in the main thread. This would also have been fixed if I had just declared the variables as `let a = new SomeClass()`

If you are facing a similar problem, DO NOT USE `JSON.stringify()`! It might look like it works at first, but what it's actually doing is deep copying your references to other objects, meaning a change to `b` won't actually update `a.ref` since `a.ref` is now just a copy of `b` and no longer a reference.